# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database " " does not exist

Tags: spring, postgresql, maven

When I try to connect to database on postgresql shell it connects and I can query it but when I try to connect to it from spring boot application, I get error saying that the database doesn't exist.

This is my application.properties file:

```
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
   spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/World 
   spring.datasource.username=postgres
   spring.datasource.password=2007
```